# Is there a way to set dependencies in Microsoft Release Management

Tags: release-management, ms-release-management

Is there a way to setup a release dependency in Microsoft release management?

i.e release B should not be released without release A being released first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is not available as yet. Today such dependencies are only within a release i.e. between environments.